# Reading contents of a text file using JavaScript throwing error

Tags: javascript, html

I'm using the following code to read the content of a text file using javascript. But when I'm getting an alert message which says "An ActiveX control on this page might be unsafe to interact with other parts of the page. Do you want to allow this interaction?" When I click on yes nothing is happening.

I'm using IE 6.0

```
function ieReadFile(filename)  
{ 
    try 
    { 
        var fso  = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");  
        var fh = fso.OpenTextFile(filename,1);  
        var contents = fh.ReadAll();  
        fh.Close();

        alert(contents);
        //return contents; 
    } 
    catch (Exception) 
    { 
        return "Cannot open file :("; 
    } 
}
```

Can anyone please help me resolve this issue?

Comment: can you get a dir listing to produce output to an alert box?

Comment: I've just tested your code and it works fine.

Comment: if you see that small yellow triangle with an !, click on that to find out what is going wrong.  to quickly identify the line which is failing, put an alert after every line.  the line after the last alert you see is where you need to focus.

Comment: I was able to retrieve the data from the text file only twice for some reason.Is this any sort of browser compatability issue ?

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine. Make sure that the path in `filename` is using double backslashes, as in `"c:\\folder\\test.txt"`, because a single backslash in JavaScript is used [to insert special characters](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_special_characters.asp).